# Rspec - archives array to match tested array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm having this class method on my Post model for getting archives

```
def self.archives
    Post.unscoped.select("YEAR(created_at) AS year, MONTHNAME(created_at) AS month, COUNT(id) AS total")
        .group("year, month, MONTH(created_at)")
        .order("year DESC, MONTH(created_at) DESC")
end
```

This is the test I have wrote for my method

```
context '.archives' do

  first = FactoryGirl.create(:post, published_at: Time.zone.now)
  second = FactoryGirl.create(:post, published_at: 1.month.ago)

  it 'returns articles archived' do
    archives = Post.archives()

    expect(
      [{
        year: first.published_at.strftime("%Y"),
        month: first.published_at.strftime("%B"),
        published: 1
      },
      {
        year: second.published_at.strftime("%Y"),
        month: second.published_at.strftime("%B"),
        published: 1
      }]
      ).to match_array(archives)
  end
end
```

However I get the following error

```
expected collection contained:  [#<Post id: nil>, #<Post id: nil>]
actual collection contained:    [{:year=>"2017", :month=>"October", :published=>1}, {:year=>"2017", :month=>"September", :total=>1}]
the missing elements were:      [#<Post id: nil>, #<Post id: nil>]
the extra elements were:        [{:year=>"2017", :month=>"October", :total=>1}, {:year=>"2017", :month=>"September", :total=>1}]
```

So although I have created 2 factories, the `archives` array is empty. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rspec standard is to use the `let` syntax for defining variables within a context or describe block. The test should look something like this:

```
describe '.archives' do
  let!(:first) { FactoryGirl.create(:post, published_at: Time.zone.now) }
  let!(:second) { FactoryGirl.create(:post, published_at: 1.month.ago) }

  it 'returns year, month, and total for articles archived' do
    actual_attributes = Post.archives.map { |post| [post.year, post.month, post.total] }
    expected_total = 1 # I don't know why the query is returning 1 for total, but including this for completeness
    expected_attributes = [first, second].map { |post| [post.created_at.year, post.created_at.strftime("%B"), expected_total] }

    expect(actual_attributes).to match_array(expected_attributes)
  end
end
```

The issue here is that you are comparing records pulled with only a few attributes (the result of your SQL query) with fully-formed records (created by your test). This test pulls the applicable attributes from both groups and compares them.

Comment: `expected collection contained:  [#<Post id: nil>, #<Post id: nil>]actual collection contained:    [#<Post id: 1, user_id: 4, title: "This is the Post title", excerpt: "This is the Post body", created_at: "2017-10-04 21:25:31", updated_at: "2017-10-04 21:25:31">]`

Comment: I've tweaked it a bit. Please try again.

Comment: I tried it my self to reverse the arrays but nothing changes

Comment: Did you add the `!` after `let`?

Comment: Try adding the additional expect shown in the edited answer, and tell me if it fails on the first expect or the second.

Comment: fails both `expect(Post.archives).to match_array([first, second])` and `expect([first, second]).to match_array(Post.archives)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155974/discussion-between-moveson-and-lykos).

Answer (score 1):

Actual array is not empty, it's an array of two Post instances with ids unset (because `Select` in `.archives` method doesn't contain id field).
You could compare expected hashes not with `archives`, but with smth like that:

```
actual = Post.archives().map do |post| 
  { year: post["year"].to_s, month: post["month"], published: post["total"] }
end

expected = [{
  year: first.published_at.strftime("%Y").to_s,
  month: first.published_at.strftime("%B"),
  published: 1
},
{
  year: second.published_at.strftime("%Y").to_s,
  month: second.published_at.strftime("%B"),
  published: 1
}]

expect(actual).to match_array(expected)
```

Comment: Not sure I understand, you mean this should be in place of my `expect`?

Comment: Clarified the answer.

Comment: `expected collection contained:  [{:year=>"2017", :month=>"October", :published=>1}, {:year=>"2017", :month=>"September", :published=>1}]actual collection contained:    []the missing elements were:      [{:year=>"2017", :month=>"October", :published=>1}, {:year=>"2017", :month=>"September", :published=>1}]`

Comment: with `let!` I get `actual collection contained:    [{:year=>2017, :month=>"October", :published=>1}, {:year=>2017, :month=>"September", :published=>1}]
the missing elements were:      [{:year=>"2017", :month=>"October", :published=>1}, {:year=>"2017", :month=>"September", :published=>1}]
       the extra elements were:        [{:year=>2017, :month=>"October", :published=>1}, {:year=>2017, :month=>"September", :published=>1}]
`

Comment: Actual collection contains year as an integer, you should convert it to string

Comment: Added `to_s` calls to the answer.